# If $\lim_m \mathbb{P}(\{\sup_{j\geq 1}{|S_{m+j}(t)-S_{m}(t)|}\leq \epsilon\})=1$ then $\mathbb{P}(\{S_n(t)\text{ is a convergent sequence}\}=1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of  random variables in Probability space.

Take $S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k}{X_k}$. We suppose that : for all $\epsilon >0$
$$\lim_m \mathbb{P}(\{\sup_{j\geq 1}{|S_{m+j}(t)-S_{m}(t)|}\leq \epsilon\})=1$$

Can we say that: $\mathbb{P}(\{\{S_n(t)\}\text{ is a convergent sequence}\}=1$

Comment: I suppose you want the limit to be $1$ for *every* $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: @uniquesolution see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can find $m_k$ such that $P(\sup_{j \geq 1} |S_{m+j}-S_m| >\frac 1  k ) <\frac  1 {2^{k}}$ when $m=m_k$. Hence $\sum_k P(\sup_{j \geq 1} |S_{m+j}-S_m| >\frac 1  k ) <\infty$. Apply Borel -Cantelli Lemma to conclude that $(S_n)$ Is Cauchy with probability $1$.

Comment: How we can apply  Borel-Cantelli's lemma?

Comment: $\sum P(A_n) <\infty$ implies that with probability $1$ only finite number of the events $A_n$ occur. This gives $\sup_{j \geq 1} |S_{m_k+j}}-S_{m_k}| \leq \frac 1  k$ for all $k$ sufficiently large. This implies that $(S_n)$ is Cauchy.